# Let K/F be a Galois extension of degree 364. Show that there is a sub extension L of K/F such that [L:F] = 4

Tags: galois-theory, sylow-theory

Let K/F be a Galois extension of degree 364.  Show that there is a sub
extension L of K/F such that [L:F] = 4

Is this argument correct?

By Sylow III, $n_7=1,$ so there is a normal subgroup of order 7 denoted by P and there is at least one subgroup of order 13 denoted by Q. Now $|P\cap Q|={e}$ because $(7,13)=1$ and so $PQ$ is a subgroup of order 7*13=91 and index 4. It's fixed field is the required extension.

I'm concerned I might need to prove that Q or PQ is normal.

Comment: Looks good to me. The Galois correspondence is between all subgroups of the Galois group. They didn't ask to show the existence of a [normal extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension).

Comment: Thanks, is it also sufficient to say that (7,13)=1 so $|P\cap Q| =\{e\}$ or do I need normal for that

Comment: If $a\in P\cap Q$ then $a^7=e=a^{13}=a^{7}a^{6}=a^6$. Therefore $a^6=e=a^7=a^6a^1=a$. The simplifications of the exponents were just Euclid's algorithm. It ended in exponent $1$, the gcd of $7$ and $13$.

Comment: You don't have to prove that $Q$ is normal, the fact that $P$ is normal is sufficient for $PQ$ to be a subgroup.

Comment: You can actually show there is a normal extension that fits the question.  The idea being that either $Q$ is normal (and you're done), or $n_{13}=14$, and thus $PN_G(Q)$ has order $182$, and is normal in $G$.  SInce $182=2\cdot\text{odd}$, there is a characteristic subgroup of order $91$.  Since characteristic in normal is normal, you're done.